# Creating different pages with one php file

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a blog that supports multiple authors.
In my navigation bar I've included a dropdown that the names of every author as links to another page that will display a description of whichever author the user clicked.

For the implementation, I was thinking of having all the links directed to a single php file that would extract out from MySQL the description of whichever author was clicked. Instead of having multiple php files - one for each author, and hard code it in. Would this be possible?

Right now I have something like this for the dropdown box.

```
<?php 
    require_once("connection.php");
    $sql = "SELECT Username FROM member_details";
$query = mysqli_query($db_Connection, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
?>
    <li><a href="author.php"><?php echo $row[0]; ?></a></li>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Not sure how to go from here.

Comment: Look at `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: *"Would this be possible?"* - Short answer: *yes*.

Comment: I'd say look only on $_POST. Get looks messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can send data/variable to the page by php url

example

in your all_author page you may have a list of authors like

```
<?php 
  $authors = get_all_author();
   foreach ($authors as $author ) {
      echo '<li><a href="author.php?q=' . $author->name() . '"> ' . $author->name() . '</a></li>';
   }
?>
```

this will output html like

```
<li><a href="author.php?q=jhon">jhon</a></li>
<li><a href="author.php?q=james">james</a></li>
<li><a href="author.php?q=peter">peter</a></li>
<li><a href="author.php?q=roy">roy</a></li>
.
.
.
.
```

you can see all the url is directed to only one page author.php and we are just sending a variable to that page, now the second part is to use that variable on the author page, and it can be access by $_GET["q"]

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_GET["q"])) header('Location: '."all_author.php");

$author_name = $_GET["q"];
$author_object = get_author($author_name);

// now you have access to this other
echo $author_object->get_decs();
echo $author_object->get_name();
echo $author_object->get_img_url();
.
.
.
.




?>
```

Comment: I see he added code, wont write myself one but don't you think it would not be better to include author file in index.php and then just use index.php?author=jhon or q=jhon for example instead of redirecting.

Comment: well its just and abstract example,i also dint know the actual code when i answered it,i mean i know in all application or frameworks they have their own routing mechanisms, which is controlled my the url , MVC stuff .. but it may make my answer a little complex so i thought not to do that :)